# Database Search with key words using jpa

Tags: java, database, jpa, optimization, query-optimization

I'm doing college work where I have to search by keywords. My entity is called `Position` and I'm using MySQL. The fields that I need to search are:

*- date*
    *- positionCode*
    *- title*
    *- location*
    *- status*
    *- company*
    *- tecnoArea*

I need to search the same word in all of these fields. To this end, I used criteria API to create a dynamic query. It is the same word for several fields and it should get the maximum possible results. Do you have any advice about how to optimize the search on the database. Should I do several queries?

**EDIT**

I will use an OR constraint.

Comment: You should simply be able to use a OR constraint in your query...

Comment: of course, i will try that. i completely forgot it. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will need to find the key word at any position within the data you will need to use LIKE with wildcards, eg. title LIKE '%manager%'. Since date and positionCode (presumably a numeric type) are not likely to contain the key word, to achieve a very small performance gain, I would omit searching these columns for the key word. Your query is going to need to do a serial read, which means that all rows in the table will need to be brought into main memory to evaluate and retrieve the result set of your query. Given a serial read is going to happen anyway, I do  not think there is too much you can do to optimize the query when searching multiple columns. I am not familiar with the "criteria api to create dynamic queries", but using dynamic queries in other systems is non-optimal - they must be parsed and evaluated every time the are run and most query optimize-rs cannot make use of the statistics for cost-based optimization to improve performance like they can with explicitly defined SQL.

Comment: The dynamic was useful to me but not on this case. i had use it before to built a query on run time according to fields the user had filled. criteria api was useful to correct the code on compile time. the link i used was [link]http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your database is.

If it is Oracle, you can use Oracle text.

The below link might be useful :

http://swiss-army-development.blogspot.com/2012/02/keyword-search-via-oracle-text.html

Comment: it's mysql. but i will save your link for the future.